# UUI installed but booting as live usb

Tags: boot, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (I think) on an external hdd using Universal Usb installer, however when I boot from the External HDD it still asks me to install.

Comment: Please give us a screenshot of what error you are getting when you boo without he USB.

Answer (score 0):

Universal USB installer installs Ubuntu as **Live image** on any USB storage device.
So in order to install ubuntu on your external hard disk you need to install Ubuntu using Universal USB installer on a pen drive first.  Then boot your pen drive and install ubuntu on your external hard disk from that live boot.